# Replacing WAV header

Tags: audio, header, wav

So here is what I've got:

The problem that I face requires me to take a specialized header from WAV1 , and put it as the header for WAV2, in order to make WAV2 work with the API that I'm using. However, whenever I try to replace the first 38 characters of WAV2 with the first 38 of WAV1, I get an error when I try to play the file, I get an error saying that it is not formatted properly. Both WAV1 and WAV2 play properly before the edit.

Do you guys have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much for your help.

-Rhynorater.

Answer (score 2):

Wav format is a standardised format (see https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ for details about file format).  I'm not sure what a "specialized" header is (perhaps you could clarify what your specialised header is?) as the format is standard - any variation would not be a wav file.

The first 38 bytes of a wav file are the header and should adhere to the standard.  You cannot copy the header from one file and use it for another as the header contains information specific to the individual file (number of channels, sample rate, file length, etc).

If you both files playback normally (how are you testing this?) I'm not sure why the API you are using is not compatible (which API are you using?).

Comment: I'm using the Skype4Py API.